# Get-FSRM - how do I get both Usage and Size in GB?

Tags: powershell

I am using the following command to retrieve stats from FSRM but cannot figure out how to return both Size and Usage in GB.  I don't understand what the @ is doing here... building an array? Help much appreciated.

```
Get-FsrmQuota | Format-Table Path, Size, @{Label="Usage GB"; 
Expression={$($_.size/1GB) -as [int] }} -auto
```

This commend displays only the Usage in GB, size is still in bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the `@{ ... }` is an expression inside your call to the Format-Table function.

Here is a blog post about it:

https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx

So in the example you shared, is structured like this:

1. Get the object(s) from the Get-FsrmQuota
2. Pipe into the Format-Table function
3. Format-Table takes Path, Size as is
4. Builds an in-memory calculated column, that will be labeled "Usage GB", based on $_.size, divided by 1GB, and marks the result as integer.

So your example actually just shows size in bytes and the same size calculated into GB's. It doesn't have an usage column or property collected from anywhere.

Update:
@mklement0 added some great information in a comment.

The `@{ ... }` is actually a *hash-table literal* and is of type `[hashtable]`. All *calculated properties* are built like that.

Answer (score 2):

Your code only deals with the `Size` property where obviously you also would like the `Usage`. To format the size as a whole number, you are using `-as [int]`. The code below uses a different way of formatting, you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings).

Also, I like using the `Select-Object` before piping to `Format-Table` to limit the number of properties beforehand, but that's up to you I guess.

```
Get-FsrmQuota | Select-Object Path, 
                              @{Label="Size GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) }}, 
                              @{Label="Usage GB"; Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Usage/1GB) }} | 
                Format-Table -AutoSize
```

### Edit

As mklement0 commented, the `Select-Object` actually comes with the cost of having extra intermediate objects being created. The code therefore could be simplified to this:

```
Get-FsrmQuota | Format-Table Path, 
                             @{Label="Size GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) }}, 
                             @{Label="Usage GB"; Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Usage/1GB) }} -AutoSize
```

The `{0:F0}` number formatting rounds the number to an integer<sup>[1]</sup> and displays the result without thousand separators. If you want thousand separators, you could also use `{0:N0}`.

Maybe also consider having the number rounded to a bit more precision, let's say to have two decimals. In that case change the `{0:F0}` into `{0:F2}`.

---

<sup>[1] Interestingly, .NET string formatting uses *half-away-from-zero* rounding, unlike `[Math]::Round()`'s default *half-to-even* rounding. That means that numbers that end in `.5` are *always* rounded up with `F0` and `N0`, whereas `[Math]::Round()` rounds `.5` *down* if the integer part is an *even number*. In .NET *Core*, starting with version 2.1, string formatting now supposedly uses half-to-even rounding too - see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)</sup>